# Weather radar overlay on MapKit

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay

I'v searched hi and low and being a novice developer I'm looking for some help. What I need to do is display weather radar over a map for a app I am trying to develop. Most of the content I have run across is outdated. My project is created using storyboards, looking for any assistance available with this issue. I have all the API's and associated info.

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What exactly are you looking for? Radar-data?

Comment: I have all the data from a private company, I just don't know how to process it and get it to overlay the map.

Answer (score 2):

Creating an overview can be quite a cumbersome task. I found [this](http://www.shawngrimes.me/2010/12/mapkit-overlays-session-1-overlay-map/) tutorial to be a good start.

Basically the tutorial says that these steps have to be done:

1. I would recommend a 600 ppi tiff. My tiff had a resolution of about 4000*2000 pixel.
2. downlaod and install gdal: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks. The installation of gdal is no joy. I can't explain every step here. Basically: first install using the complete installer. Then install numPy. Then copy gdal in the path with the terminal.
3. load the tiff into Google Maps to get the coordinates of the 4 corners.
4. create the vrt file with gdal. The command will look similar to this string: gdal_translate -of VRT -a_srs EPSG:4326 -gcp 0 0 7.435822 46.953453 -gcp 2285 0 7.460397 46.953453 -gcp 2285 1479 7.460397 46.942342 -gcp 0 1479 7.435822 46.942342 MN_A.tiff MN_A.vrt
5. Create the tiles with [MapTiler](http://www.maptiler.org). The Mac version didn't work for me, but the Windows version did the job.
6. You need to add these tiles to the project and create a folder reference for them. The code of the WWDC video Session 127 shows how that works.
7. repeat step 3-5 until the overlay works fine.